# Custom TextBox in Mapnik

Tags: python, mapnik

I'm using Mapnik in Python for batch creation of png files from my raster layers. `<RasterSymbolizer>` from XML style works perfect in my case. However I would like to put a small text annotation on each png file with the filename and maybe a small copyright note. Is it possible to do it within the Mapnik style?